# Where clause, multiple sets of conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am trying to produce a single table query result with error payment data filtered out by the conditions below. I am unable to get the query to filter out all of the sets of conditions, only the first 3. I have tried different ordering as well as making the last two condition sets a sub-query.

How can I filter out all the below conditions?

Again, 1,2 and 3 seem to have the desired result.Conditions 4 and 5 function, just not when following conditions 1,2 and 3

```
 select [history].[id] 
            [history].[trans],
            CAST([history].[paid_dt] AS Date),
            CAST([history].[due_dt] AS Date),

     FROM [history]

     LEFT OUTER JOIN [information] ON [history].[id] = [information].[id]

    --Condition 1--
            WHERE NOT  ([history].[trans]  IN
            ('TRSF',
             'TRR',
              'BEG',
             'DTR',
             'LTC',
           ))

             OR
    --Condition 2--
            (CONVERT(date,[paid_dt]) = '2015-12-30'
            AND [trans] = 'ADJE') 

            OR
    -- Condition 3--
            ([history].[paid_dt] = [information].[date]
            AND [history].[trans] LIKE '%ADJE%'
            AND [history].[due_dt] < '2017-01-01')

    --Condition 4--
            OR  
                 (datepart(dd, [paid_dt]) = 8) 
        --assume there is more to this condition--


           OR
    --Condition 5--
                 (CONVERT(date,[history].[paid_dt]) = '2018-01-08' 
             and [history].[trans] = 'MANR'));
```

Just looking for insight as how to address

Comment: So condition 4 and 5 are not working?  Your question is a bit confusing, and one of the conditions not working is basically omitted.  There is no closing bracket on condition 4 (I assume thats omitted?) and there are a few too many closing quotes on condition 5.

Comment: Don't know whether this is due to a botched edit, or it was this way originally, but the braces in conditions #4 and #5 are unmatched

Comment: it was botched edit. corrected

Comment: that NOT at the beginning is throwing me... are you wanting any of the 5 predicate sets NOT to be true in order to return rows? I have to dig and see if NOT takes precedence in order of operations....

Comment: confirmed: NOT beats OR.

Comment: I want the conditions NOT to be true. So any condition that is true would not be in the result

Comment: you might want to provide sample data and desired result before delving to your sql query

Comment: I think my question is more general than that. I'm asking how to approach a where clause where you need multiple sets of conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'NOT' acts only on one condition.  If you don't want any of the other conditions to be returned if true... try surrounding all conditions following the 'NOT' keyword in parentheses.  Also, double check where you have your parentheses.  I'm still seeing an odd number of those maybe due to pasting.

```
WHERE NOT 
    (
        (Condition 1)
         OR
        (Condition 2)
     )
```

You can also try getting away from the 'NOT' keyword by using <> references instead.